# prove the existence of convex sets containing compact set

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis, compactness

How could I prove that every compact set is contained in a convex set/s?  Seems like an obvious claim but I want to formalize this idea.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Every subset of $\mathbb R^n$ is contained in a convex set, namey the whole space... Perhaps you mean this: every compact set is contained in a *compact* convex set?

Comment: Well that's what I want to prove next but as part of that proof I want to first generate a set containing all the convex sets which contain some compact set.  Then I'll take the intersection of those and proceed from there.  I guess I could've worded my question better by asking how to generate  a set containing all such convex sets

Comment: Oh, you're talking about the [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull).

Comment: Yup, I'm trying to prove that such a convex set exists.  Namely, that a unique convex set B contains some compact set A, and B lies in all compact convex sets that contain A.  So my thinking is to take the intersection of the set containing all convex sets containing A, and then proving that the intersection of convex sets is also convex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are working on a normed vector space. Every compact subset is bounded, hence contained in a ball, which is convex.

Comment: @lhf true, edited

Comment: I didn't ask the question in quite the way I wanted to, however you gave a perfect response to the question I asked so I'll accept your answer and re-ask my question.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to restrict yourself to Banach spaces then you can say a bit more; if $K$ is a compact set in a Banach space then its *closed convex hull* (the smallest closed convex set containing $K$) is itself compact. This is the content of *Mazur's compactness theorem*.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Well I want to prove the existence of the convex hull.  So what I want is to generate a set containing all the convex sets containing the compact set, then I can finish the proof from there.  But I'm not sure how to formalize the set containing all convex sets containing the compact set